# How to transfer IBAction method of the class into another class

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have created IBAction method with help of Storyboard. How can access this method from another class?

```
- (IBAction)display:(ID) sender
{
}
```

Comment: create a public method and in its implementation call your display method.Now in other class call the public method

Comment: I have up voted urs hope to get it back in my answer too

Answer (score 0):

Try using as below
FirstViewController.h

```
@interface FirstViewController: UIViewController
- (void)GetItNow;
```

FirstViewController.m

```
- (void)GetItNow{
    NSLog(@"I acheived");    } 

  - (IBAction)goToSecondView:(id)sender {

    SecondViewController* Second= [[SecondViewControlleralloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
    rqVC.addId = self.addId;
    [self.view addSubview:Second.view];

}
```

SecondViewController.h

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) id delegate;
```

SecondViewController.m

```
- (IBAction)Action_LoadFunds:(id)sender {
    [self.view removeFromSuperview];
    [_delegate GetItNow];

}
```

Comment: that solution would look much nicer if you'd implement a proper protocol for handling delegates.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion . can you edit my post to show me hw u do implement that

Comment: i need to call this Action_LoadFunds method through the programatically and IBAction with help of storyboard. Is it possible to call the IBAction method by code?

Comment: [_delegate Action_LoadFunds:nil]  Try using this or [self Action_LoadFunds:nil]